# (C) Program doesn't print all values from input file

Tags: c

Working with C.

OK so this is probably something obvious but for some reason my program will only print a certain number of values from a .dat input file as opposed to printing all of them. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int N = 0;
int j;
float i;

const char Project_Data[] = "FloatValues.dat";

FILE *input = fopen(Project_Data, "r");

if(input != (FILE*) NULL)
{
    while(fscanf(input, "%e", &i) == 1)
    {
        printf("%e\n",i);
        ++N;
    }
    printf("\t The number of values in this file is: %d\n", N);

    fclose(input);
}
else
    printf("Input file could not be read.\n");

return(0);
}
```

Yeah, so there's about 100000 values or so to be printed yet I only seem to be able to get 20000. The values in the file are ordered sequentially and the compiler only seems to start printing nearer the bottom of the file, after about 80000 or so values.

Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: could some of the value not be in `%e` format?

Comment: Please show a few lines of the data file.

Comment: error check the return value of fscanf and print errno to isolate your problem.

Comment: Here's some of the data values: 7.7600000e+00   1.4475864e+00
   7.7700000e+00   1.2148609e+00
   7.7800000e+00   2.4770279e+00
   7.7900000e+00   2.0807041e+00
   7.8000000e+00   2.3333046e+00
 Just selected a random strand. Like I said the data flows sequentially yet at a glance the values appear to be unordered because they form right diagonals on the page instead of columns.

Comment: Will follow the other advice now thanks all of you.

Comment: In a tradition dating back to Fortran II, and certainly from the earliest C books, the variable `i` is normally an `int`.  It is unusual indeed to use any other type for `i`, and to a lesser extent, `j`.  It isn't wrong; it is unusual, that's all.

Comment: yes, apologies. j shouldn't be there (must have left it in from previous code) and i was initially an integer but I changed it when I realised what kind of data values I was working with. regardless, i've been fiddling round with this for the past hour with no luck. i'm far from an experienced programmer yet i've managed for all the rest of my code to work; it's just this segment that's baffling me.